# can you set $_SESSION['userName'] as a dir

Tags: php

code that gives my sessions username:   works perfectly after login and gives the username

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>
```

Now I want to count all files in a folder, the folder's name is the username of the person logged in. But I can't get it to work somehow...

```
<?php $pm = 0; 
    $dir = './berichten/<?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $pm++;
        }
    }
echo $pm;
 ?>
```

Comment: You're opening PHP tags inside PHP code, just concatenate the variable with .

Answer (score 4):

Your string formatting was a bit off, try this:

```
$dir = './berichten/' . $_SESSION['userName'] . '/';
```

These kind of notations (`<?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>`) are usually found outside of PHP-code, for example HTML. You don't need to open PHP tags or echo's inside a PHP echo :)

Comment: Call to a member function read() on a non-object  i get as error

Comment: Is `session_start();` in all your files? @user3090697 and where does `read()` come into the picture? It's not in your posted code. You're obviously using something else with this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall if `readdir` can handle a directory path with the trailing slash.  Besides [Aquillo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790212/198536), try removing the trailing slash.

```
$dir = './berichten/' . $_SESSION['userName'];
```

Comment: Call to a member function read() on a non-object  i get as error